# Como abrir CD-ROM em C?

Tags: c, windows, winapi

Estou querendo criar um algoritmo em C para abrir e fechar a unidade de CD-ROM, dei uma olhada em alguns tutoriais mas eles acabaram não funcionando. Gostaria de saber quais bibliotecas deveria usar.

Comment: Depende de SO. E é mais fácil na shell do sistema

Comment: @JeffersonQuesado Windows 7. Sei que em Linux o código é bem curtinho. Mas no Windows, pelos tutoriais que achei não consegui. Então pensei em criar um mesmo, mas queria saber quais bibliotecas usar.

Comment: @Marinero: Bem, achei a pergunta bastante relevante, com as TAGS corretas, e poderia agregar muito à comunidade SOpt: https://pastebin.com/qZW7aEkP

Comment: Talvez eu esteja arriscando, mas votei por reabrir dando a oportunidade do Lacobus responder (não vou afirmar que funciona, porque não é algo que domino). ps: @Lacobus eu não domino C tanto quanto vocês, mas creio que `true` e `false` necessite de um `define`, ou enum ou até mesmo `<stdbool.h>`, claro que talvez você tenha presumido que isso é algo intuitivo para o autor, mas as vezes ele pode iniciante.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento: Você está certo. O tipo `bool`, e as constantes `true` e `false` são exclusivos do `C++` e não fazem parte do padrão `C`.

Comment: @Lacobus já votei pra reabrir, faltam 3 votos, agora é só aguardar. PS: O `stdbool.h` foi introduzido no [C99](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_C#C89) se eu não me engano.

Comment: Tenta o seguinte -----
#include <windows.h>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
typedef MCIERROR WINAPI (*CDROM)(const char*,char*,unsigned,HWND);
CDROM pCD;
void AbrirCD(){
 pCD("Set CDAudio Door Open",NULL,0,NULL);
}
void FecharCD(){
 pCD("Set CDAudio Door Closed",NULL,0,NULL);
}

Comment: int menu(){
 int choice;
 cout << "você deseja abrir ou fechar o drive de cd?\n";
 cout << "[1]Abrir\n";
 cout << "[2]Fechar\n";
 cin >> choice;
 switch(choice){
  case 1:
   AbrirCD();
  break;
  case 2:
   FecharCD();
  break;
  default:
   cout << "opcao inexistente\n";
   Sleep(250);
   exit(0);
 }
 exit(0);
 return 0;
}

Comment: int main(){
 HINSTANCE dll = LoadLibrary("winmm.dll");
 if(!dll)
  return 1;
 pCD = (CDROM)GetProcAddress(dll,"mciSendStringA");
 if(!pCD)
  return 1;
 menu();
 return 0;
}

Comment: Copia a sequencia e cola, em seguencia e executa, nao consegui responder de outra forma, sou novo aqui :S